# Very high load, apparently caused by pdflush

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, io, high-load

I have a server that's running CentOS 5, and it will periodically (a couple of times a day) have enormous spikes in load, and the whole server will grind to a halt. After a couple of minutes, the load will go back down and everything returns to normal.

I *suspect* it has something to do with I/O and maybe a bad disk, but as the disks use hardware RAID, I'm not sure how to find out what's going wrong (smartctl just says "Device does not support SMART").

So anyway, what I see from `top` is:

```
top - 08:51:03 up 73 days,  7:45,  1 user,  load average: 69.00, 58.31, 46.89
Tasks: 316 total,   2 running, 314 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 11.0%us,  1.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 15.2%id, 72.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8299364k total,  7998520k used,   300844k free,    15480k buffers
Swap: 16779884k total,     4788k used, 16775096k free,  6547860k cached
```

As you can see, the load is ridiculously high. And `vmstat` shows:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
24 16   5632 296080  23392 6317688    0    0     3    28    0    0  7  1 89  3  0
 0 22   5632 292644  23600 6325372    0    0    69 18781 1985 2318  9  2 14 75  0
 1 23   5656 299472  23756 6299140    0    0    44 18667 2075 3382 14  2 13 71  0
 0 23   5656 304756  24152 6295696    0    0    88 17002 1880 1445  4  1 16 78  0
 0 24   5656 296736  24488 6356564    0    0    60 17967 1841  990  2  1 20 76  0
 0 21   5672 302248  24764 6388424    0    0    66 17216 1820  749  2  1 24 73  0
```

It's the really high "wa" value that looks way off to me. Also, `iotop` gives:

```
Total DISK READ: 77.37 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 15.81 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                      
25647 be/4 apache     73.50 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % httpd
24387 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
23813 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
25094 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 96.72 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
25093 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
25095 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
25091 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
24389 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
24563 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % [pdflush]
24390 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s   23.21 K/s 96.71 % 99.99 % httpd
24148 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 96.71 % 99.99 % httpd
24699 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % httpd
23973 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % httpd
24270 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % httpd
24298 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s 1918.82 K/s 96.71 % 99.02 % httpd
  628 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 97.51 % [kjournald]
25092 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 96.72 % [pdflush]
24258 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 96.71 % [pdflush]
23814 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 96.71 % [pdflush]
24388 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.02 % 96.71 % [pdflush]
25545 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.19 % 92.73 % httpd
25274 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 92.38 % httpd
24801 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    5.84 M/s 99.99 % 91.63 % httpd
25281 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    5.75 M/s  0.00 % 91.33 % httpd
26115 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  9.60 % 19.26 % httpd
25561 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    3.87 K/s  0.00 %  9.66 % httpd
26035 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  9.63 % httpd
```

Finally, I get the following from `sar -d 5 0`:

```
Linux 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5PAE (ausbt.com.au)  23/08/12

08:55:45          DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
08:55:50       dev8-0    877.25    103.79  29306.19     33.53    158.81    179.28      1.14     99.84
08:55:50       dev8-1      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
08:55:50       dev8-2      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
08:55:50       dev8-3    877.25    103.79  29306.19     33.53    158.81    179.28      1.14     99.84
```

This has only recently stated happening (at least, I only noticed it recently) and nothing on the server has changed, so that's why I'm suspecting maybe some kind of hardware failure, but I'm not sure where to begin looking.

**Update**

Thanks to Mark Wagner's hint, I did an `strace` of one of the processes that was doing MB/s of I/O and discovered that it was writing to files called "/tmp/magick-XXXXXXX". Here's the output of `ls -l /tmp/magick-XX*":

```
-rw------- 1 apache apache 1854881318400 Aug 20 04:26 /tmp/magick-XXrQahSe
-rw------- 1 apache apache 1854881318400 Aug 20 04:26 /tmp/magick-XXTaXatz
-rw------- 1 apache apache 1854881318400 Aug 20 04:26 /tmp/magick-XXtf25pe
```

Wow! Those files were from a couple of days ago, but there's also files from today that are a similar size. My code dynamically generates thumbnails of images using ImageMagick so perhaps there's a corrupted image somewhere that's causing ImageMagick to freak out and write 1.6 terrabyte files to /tmp.

I'll do some more poking around and post an update when I find more. Thanks everybody for the hints so far.

Comment: Apache PIDs 24801 and 25281 are doing by far the most I/O: 5.84 M/s  and 5.75 M/s, respectively. I use `iotop -o` to exclude processes not doing I/O.

Comment: *Some* hardware raid controllers expose raw drive interfaces as SCSI generic devices `sg#` for the purpose of querying SMART information ([see here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-checking-sas-sata-disks-behind-adaptec-raid-controllers/) ), but I'm not sure how to tell which sg# devices, if any, are which drives.

Comment: My bet is that you have some process that is calling `fsync`, forcing a massive writeout. Tuning is, by default, for great average behavior with the occasional explosion. You can tune for worse average behavior but better worst-case behavior. You can drop `dirty_ratio` or `dirty_expire_centisecs`. (What RAID controller are you using?)

Comment: @MarkWagner Thanks for the hint, good spotting! I've updated the question with what I've discovered so far, but I think you've given me enough of a hint to continue the investigation :)

Comment: Can you provide information on what hardware components you're using?

Comment: Thanks all for the input, but @MarkWagner's suggestion was the one. In the end it was a request for an image thumbnail that was 300000x200000 pixels which was causing ImageMagick to go nuts. I don't know if it was some smart alec trying to DOS us or just a weird link somewhere, but anyway I fixed the code to limit the size of thumbnails we generate :) Mark if you want the rep, you can convert your comment to an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Sounds like a DoS attack to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment converted to answer.

Apache PIDs 24801 and 25281 are doing by far the most I/O: 5.84 M/s and 5.75 M/s, respectively. I use `iotop -o` to exclude processes not doing I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can trust iotop since you aren't at a kernel level it's compatible with.

I'm on the same kernel (2.6.18) as you and I can't get iotop -o to even work.. it doesn't show me only IO producing processes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the two processes that were shown doing ~5MB/s of I/O in my screengrab above were *definitely* doing a lot of I/O.